# Matplotlib widget Cursor does not reappear after disconnecting/reconnecting

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, cursor

In an application of mine, I want to be able to disable and re-enable a Cursor widget in a figure. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to make the Cursor reappears if it has been disabled before. I have tried several methods of the Cursor widget (set_active, disconnect_events...) but with no success. Please consider the following:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def onevent(event):
    print "you clicked!"

plt.ion()
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
c=Cursor(ax) # the cursor appears on my figure. Fine.

c.connect_event('button_press_event',onevent) # the cursor is connected. Fine
c.disconnect_events() # the cursor is disconnected, and has disappeared. Fine
c.connect_event('button_press_event',onevent) # the cursor is connected again (fine), but HAS NOT REAPPEARED (not fine!)
```

Can you reproduce this behaviour?
I get this behaviour with either qt, tk or wx backends.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I want by disconnecting the Cursor (c.disconnect_event()) and recreating the cursor (c=Cursor(ax)) when I need it again...
the method set_active(False|True) does make the cursor disappear and reappear, but doesn't disconnect it from the "event".